# Cannot use UIButton when using CABasicAnimation to move it

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, cabasicanimation

I am trying to animate a UIButton so that it moves around on the screen, but once it animates, it crashes when I try actually using it as a button.

Is this not allowed? How can this be done?

I tried putting the button inside a UIView and then animating the view instead - still crashed.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        CATransaction.begin()

        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.fromValue = [view.layer.frame.width, 200]
        animation.toValue = [0, 200]
        animation.duration = 25.0
        animation.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude

        button.layer.add(animation, forKey: "animatePosition")

        CATransaction.commit()
    }
```

It throws the following exception when trying to click the button:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI pointValue]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2816c4a40'

Comment: Try using passing a `CGPoint` instead of an array. Make sure your IBAction it is properly connected to your button.

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you, I tried this and it still crashes: 
animation.fromValue = CGPoint(x: view.layer.frame.width, y: 200.0)
animation.toValue = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 200.0)

Comment: I think your issue is at your button connection. Edit your question and post the IBAction that should be called when pressing the button. Also you should provide at which line is your error occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the array of two numeric values, not the expected position type.
The type of the value that is expected by `CABasicAnimation` is `NSValue(cgPoint:)`.

You'll fix that crash by this:

```
animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: view.layer.frame.width, y: 200.0))
animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 200))
```

Comment: Thank you, so I tried both what you and @Leo suggested and it still crashes
animation.fromValue = CGPoint(x: view.layer.frame.width, y: 200.0)
animation.toValue = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 200.0)

Comment: What is the crash log after you've changed to `NSValue`?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI pointValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x283c16620'

Comment: Add the `All Exceptions` breakpoint and check the line on which the debugger stops. https://learnappmaking.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/debugging-xcode-swift-4-exception.jpg

Comment: not sure if it matters, but once the animation is done and the button shows up again - if you click it, it still crashes. (and of course if I cancel the animation it doesn't crash)

Comment: -[__NSArrayI pointValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x283238fa0 @Eugene

Comment: It seems that the line of the code where it crashes, is somewhere else, not in the code snippet that you posted, since there are no arrays anymore after you've done modifications that I suggested.. Again, add the breakpoint and find the exact call stack and the line in the code that causes the crash.